# Blog with comments on ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, blogs

What is the most painless way to make a blog with social login in ASP.Net MVC4 web-site?

I already have SQL Server membership, so I want current users to be able to comment under their names and new users to use social login. 
So I need

- Administration: comments moderation, user management
- Blog: adding new pages to the blog last, posts widget, search posts,
  display posts based on tag etc

I am sure it's a common task, but I haven't found a solution so far.

Update: I need comments hierarchy. All blog engines I saw so far don't have comments hierarchy and they also don't recognize logged in user.

Comment: Are you planning to build one from scratch or use one of the existing engines?

Comment: I want to find an Open Source solution

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of these: all are free, open source, .NET

http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

http://www.funnelweblog.com/

http://www.dasblog.info/